# Textbox shifting when printing [MS Word 2010]

Tags: printing, textbox, ms-word

I have a document in MS Word 2010 that contains several textboxes. The document looks completely fine in print preview; however, when printed the texboxes shift position. The strange thing is I've tried printing the document on another printer and it works just fine. It also works if I try to print it from Word 2007. I ran the compatability checker in Word and it came back with the following message: "Some text box positioning will change".

Anyone have a clue what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/compatibility-checker-errors-HA010117654.aspx), the message appears due to the following:

> In text boxes, text that is centered vertically or aligned to the
>   bottom will be permanently aligned to the top even if you later
>   convert the document to Office Word 2007 format.

[This site](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/compatibility-changes-between-versions-HA010370116.aspx) has similar text

> In text boxes, text that is centered vertically or aligned to the
>   bottom will be permanently aligned to the top even if you later
>   convert the document to Word 2010 format.

Either way, if a different printer attached to the same system prints it correctly then you will want to see if the printer that fails has an updated (or alternate) print driver.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when printing a **.doc** file in Word for Mac 2011.  I saved it as a **.docx** file instead, and that fixed it!